# Access database in Cordova

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I am very new to cordova developing. I am trying to develop one login page in android app, i need to access username and password from database for checking credential. Now i am hosting one web service and just pass the user name and password to that service using ajax request and proceed based on value returned from webservice. I dont know is this the correct procedure?. I am sending user name and password through ajax post, i think its insecure.Can you please suggest the best wasy to access database in cordova? I am using visual studio IDE for developing. I used following code to send username and pwd to webservice.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost\service\Controller',// hostedd in iis
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: 'user1', password: 'pwd' }),
    sucess: function (data) {
        //perform operation for login success
    },
    error: function () {

    }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Any code snippet to show us ? This is (almost) mandatory here...

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost\service\Controller',// hostedd in iis
        data: JSON.stringify({ username: 'user1', password: 'pwd' }),
        sucess: function (data) {
            //perform operation for login success
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    }). I used this code snippet to send user name and pwd to webservice.

Comment: First of all, your url doesn't have http or https, it should. Second, don't use localhost, localhost is "this machine", the connection might work on simulators/emulators, but will fail on real devices, use the local IP or host it on internet and link the internet url. If you use https it shouldn't be incecure

Comment: i just use localhost for developing purpose, once i get complete i will ost this service in any domain and will provide http or https url as like u mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. If you use external urls, then white listen them:
   http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html
2. Use only https.
3. Verify the footprint of your cert by using this plugin:

http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

4. Don't send the password, send the hash of the password. Use the same algorithm which you use in the backend for creating the hash.
5. Create a device UUID, save it on the device and send it to the backend and save it the first time, the device called the backend. Use this UUID for logging the device activity.
6. On every request to the backend, send the device UUID and check it.
7. Make sure, that you have a way in the backend to stop the activity of a device and user.
8. In some of my apps, I use the device UUID for individual encryption.
9. If you want, you can encrypt your whole app by using this plugin:

http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

10. In some of my apps (B2B apps), I use an authorization which is working via QR code. In the backend I create some individual «secure Infos» and show them as an QR code. In the app you have a barcodescanner which scans the info , which is then saved on the device. Works great and this is a good way to have individual keys on the devices.